# Bootstrap datepicker not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jsp, datepicker, struts

This is the screenshot of datepicker window

[image]

I am creating a web page for mobile. So for this I have used meta with view port attribute. I added the bootstrap datepicker but its shows blank screen in horizontal mode and when I view it in vertical mode it shows calender with excess blank space. The same code worked fine in another page. I tried removing the meta tag for view port but no effect.
Here is my code :

Javascript :

```
$('.transactionDate').datepicker({
        orientation: "auto right",
        format : "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startDate : $('#start_date').val(),
        endDate : new Date(),
        todayHighlight : true,
        autoclose : true,
        todayBtn : 'linked',
    });
```

HTML(JSP):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="<html:rewrite page='/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css'/>" />

<script type="text/javascript"
src="<html:rewrite page='/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' />"> </script>

<html:textname="AA8_AAA01Form" property="transactionDate" styleClass="form-element  transactionDate" style="width:210px; background-color: white;" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: Can you try removing your `width:210px` property from inline css and add `font-size: 62.5%;`?

Comment: I did but nothing changed.

Comment: remove comma (,) after todayBtn : 'linked'